# Calculus inverse tangent line

Tags: calculus, inverse

Question is:

Let $ f(x)=(1/2)x^3+6x+4 $ and let $y=f^{-1}(x)$ be the inverse function of f.  Determine the x-coordinates of the two points on the graph of the inverse function where the tangent line is perpendicular to the straight line $y=-12x-9$.

Since (I believe) the inverse of the function is much too complicated to calculate easily, I figure the solution will involve the use of this formula: $\frac{d}{dx} f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$, but I have not figured out how.

Also, I think it is pretty obvious that the slope of the tangent will be $1/12$

Comment: Note that f^-1(x) returns $f^-1(x)$. While f^{-1}(x) yields $f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: If the slope of the tangent to the inverse is 1/12, then what is the slope of the tangent with respect to the original function? And what is the derivative of the original function?

Comment: Thank you I think I figured it out!